# Width of the kendo controls are not assigning dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I am using `kendo ui` controls like `dropdownlist`, `datepicker` etc. I want to dynamically set the width for the control on button click. But the changes are not reflecting. I have written the code like

Html

```
<input id='Dropdownlist' type='text' style='width:150px;' />
<input type='text' id='width' style='width:100px;' />
<button id='changewidth'>Change Width</button>
```

Javascript

```
$("#Dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
dataSource:["First","Second"]
});

$("#changewidth").on('click',function(){
 $("#Dropdownlist").css('width',200);    
 $("#width").css('width',200);
});
```

The styling is applying for the text box but not applying for the `kendo ui` controls. How can i get rid of this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer

```
 $("#Dropdownlist").parent().css('width',"200px");
```

will did the trick for me.